# How to change portable Firefox and Google Chrome icon in Windows 7 taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, google-chrome, desktop-customization

I'm customizing my desktop based on the one that I saw yesterday at [howtogeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/news/this-customized-windows-desktop-has-impressive-icons/190/). As you can see I am able to change the icon of Firefox, but when I launch it, it opens another one (I now have two Firefox icons on the taskbar). What do I do so that when I click the one that is pinned on the taskbar, it doesn't open up another?

And how do I change the Chrome icon when I launch it? They're both portable.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a shortcut to whatever program, and then pin that to the taskbar. The icons of shortcuts are much more amenable to change.

I don't know what's causing the firefox icon to duplicate, so that might still happen.

Comment: you're right with that, it still duplicates.

Comment: It still change icon during execution. FAILS! on Windows10

Answer (score 0):

I tried to change the icon in shortcut and its fails on Windows7.  The method here under does not replace the icon in the shortcut.  But now, you know where to find a suitable icon...

See there : https://portableapps.com/node/13096

How to change Firefox Portable icon?

It's not a question but an issue to do it because I need it and I wasn't able to found how to do. Perhaps it would be helpfull for someone else.

To change the Firefox Portable icon, you need a .ICO file, rename it into main-window.ico then put it into the path \FirefoxPortable\App\firefox\chrome\icons\default if they not exist, create all missed folders.

Note that is seems to works only with older versions.